# Axes Rotation. Why do we multiply the xy-axes by the inverse of the rotation matrix to get the new axes?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't understand why we multiply the xy-cartesian coordinate system by the inverse of the rotation matrix to rotate it counterclockwise by a certain angle and get a new x'y'-coordinate system. The original rotation matrix doesn't already do the counterclockwise rotation about the origin?
I don't understand why this formula is wrong:
x' = xcos(μ) - ysin(μ)       y' = xsin(μ) + ycos(μ)

Comment: This is a confusing thing, but that's life: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quirk is probably easier to get your head around if you don't rotate, but rather *scale* the coordinate axes. For instance, if we *double* the length of our basis vectors, the apparent result is that we *halve* the components of any column vector.

In exactly the same way, if we rotate the basis vectors by an angle of $\theta$ *counterclockwise*, the apparent result is that the representation of any vector in the new coordinate system looks like it have been rotated by an angle of $\theta$ *clockwise*.

So, given a column vector $v$ and an angle $\theta$, the matrix multiplication
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}v
$$
tells you what you get if you rotate the vector $v$ by an angle of $\theta$ counterclockwise. However, if you are rotating the *coordinate system* by an angle of $\theta$ counterclockwise, it is the operation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}v
$$
that tells you what the components of the *unchanged* vector $v$ are in the *new coordinate system*.

Comment: Even more basic: $\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos x$, but the graph of $\cos x$ is the graph of $\sin x$ shifted *left* by $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @saulspatz Sure. But that's a bit outside the realm of linear algebra (the sine function isn't actually linear, and neither are translations). Also, rotating the plane was the concrete operation asked about here.